# Conditional MySQL query according to year

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with prices like

```
id  element_id  daily_price   weekly_price   since          until 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2           400           2800        2017-01-01   2017-05-31
2       2           500           3500        2017-06-01   2017-12-31
3       2           600           4200        2018-01-01   2018-05-31
4       2           700           4900        2018-06-01   2018-12-31
```

I would like to do a single query that gets the minimum daily_price and weekly_price for the current year. In case, there are no prices set for the current year, then it should get the same min prices for the last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
select min(daily_price), min(weekly_price)
    from table 
    where element_id = 2
    AND year(since) = (select max(year(since))
                       from table
                       where element_id = 2);
```

or this if you want to use a join instead of subquery:

```
select min(daily_price), min(weekly_price)
from table a, (select max(year(since)) as year, element_id
                     from table
                     where element_id = 2) b
where a.element_id = 2
and a.element_id = b.element_id
and year(since) = b.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this

```
SELECT MIN(daily_price) as minDailyPrice, Max(weekly_price) as maxWeeklyPrice 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE until <= 'current_year_here' 
ORDER BY until DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I like the idea, but if I´m not wrong in the example is returning daily_price = 400 and that is wrong if current year exists then should return the min of the current year, in the example: 500.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join with year, min daily and min weekly subquery

```
  select  a.id, a.year, b. min_daily, c.min_weekly 
  from  (

    select id, max(year(until)) year 
    from my_table  
    group by id 

    ) a 
    inner join  (
    select id, year(until) year,  min(daily_price)  min_daily
    from my_table  
    group by id ,  year(until)  

    ) b on a.id = b.id and a.year=b.year 

    inner join  (
      select  id,  year(until) year, min(weekly_price) min_weekly
      from my_table  
      group by id ,  year(until) 
      ) c on a.id = c.id and a.year=c.year
```

Comment: I´m getting error: Unknown column c.year 'on clause'

Comment: Please see my answer below. What do you think?

Comment: id think that your query could fail for chooese the right year .. anyway i have updated  the answer  an  seems that my answer  give you useful suggestion  ..